# How can I set the animation duration of a UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

Subclassing `UIPickerView` and overriding `-scrollAnimationDuration` allowed one to change the animation duration of the picker view prior to iOS 5. Does anyone know another trick for setting the animation duration of a picker view in iOS 5?

This works pre-iOS 5:

```
// Subclass of UIPickerView
@implementation SpinDurationView

- (double)scrollAnimationDuration { return 2.7; }

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this ?

```
    CGPoint newLogoutCenter = CGPointMake(160, 364);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
    pickerview.center = newLogoutCenter;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

I use this animation code for UIButton. UILable, etc.. I never used for UIPickerView. But you can try.

Comment: do i add it in the subclass of pickerview instead of the line above ?

Comment: Did anyone else get this to work - all I want is to increase the duration of spin for UIPickerView.